# How can we fix :"could not initialize a memory descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_maxpooling_op.cc:578" error while using InceptionV3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to train InceptionV3 on a dataset that I have.I am using python3.5 on spyder with keras and tensorflow as backend.

I am getting the following error:

could not initialize a memory descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_maxpooling_op.cc:578

I have tried installing tensor flow with conda install -c anaconda tensorflow but that didn't removed the error.

Comment: I found some stuff on github, have you tried there? Maybe in here in these questions?
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23145